# How do I delete a list or card in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have recently been exploring the new web application [Trello](http://blog.fogcreek.com/fog-creek-launches-trello-2/) and I accidentally created a `list` by mistake.

I figured out how to remove the list from the board by archiving it but in reality I would like to delete it completely (it was a mistake and I don't want it cluttering the archive).

Is there a way to completely delete a `list` and/or `card` in Trello?

Comment: The ability to delete a cards is in development, see https://trello.com/card/board/perma-delete-cards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e2dc7159952cfa21e00242f

Comment: While waiting for the delete feature to be implemented, I simulate delete by removing the title, description, etc. Then I archive.

Comment: If you'd like this feature to be added to trello, vote it up at https://trello.com/card/board/delete-lists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4ed67f95f75e25831e02b0bc

Comment: Yes indeed. Neither their or here we seem to get a clear response about where that delete thing is anyway.

Comment: If your reason is merely the feeling that you don't want outcome of your poking  to disturb your view, you can create Trash board and/or list, and keep there well - trash.

If you want to remove your sensitive data 'from cloud', then it is actually in cards, not lists or boards.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Unfortunately, **no** for lists and boards (for the moment). Card delete has been added since launch. [Trello blog](http://blog.trello.com/trello-common-questions/) gives the answer as follows:

> **Can I delete a board/list/card and make it go away forever?**
>
> Trello doesn't have board or list delete. Archive and close have a
>   similar effect. Card delete has been added since launch.
>
> To delete a card, first archive it, then click delete from the sidebar
>   back of the card OR click 'view archive' from the board sidebar, find
>   the card, and delete it.

I've also found this bug annoying and contacted them.

**Edit:** Card delete has been added since launch.

Comment: As someone else mentioned, there is a difference between something you want to archive and something you did just by mistake. The same question goes to: "how to delete a board"? If you could at least undo something you created a few minutes ago it would be nice. If there is no Delete button, there should be an Undo button. Otherwise, you really get the feeling you need to be very careful on what you create. It discourages exploring what the product can do for you if there is no way to destroy experiments and mistakes.

Comment: An extension to a fantastic answer - archiving an empty list deletes it.
So you may want to delete all the cards and then archive the empty list to get rid of it altogether.

Comment: Perhaps update with instructions for *how* (it is extremely unintuitive)? Or at least link to [fiatjaf's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/how-do-i-delete-a-list-or-card-in-trello/80600#80600)?

Answer (score 33):

There is no Delete options for lists in Trello but there is one way to do it.

Step#1: Create a new Board with any name.

Step#2: Go to the list you want to delete, and find the 3 dots next to the list title.

Step#3: Go to "Move list" and select the board that you have created, click "Move"

Step#4: Go to the new board containing the moved list.

Step#5: Within the new board under menu click "more" and then "Close Board".

Step#6: Once the board is closed, the option "Permanently Delete Board…" appears to delete the board and the list along with it.

Comment: I was just thinking to try this if no other way of deleting can be found. It seems to get the job done.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution!!

Comment: I'd consider this as the answer now.

Answer (score 12):

At the moment, there is no way to "delete" a list on Trello - you can only archive it. Do this by clicking the arrow next to the list title:

[image: it looks like this]

and clicking "Archive This List". Archiving a list removes it from all views, just like deleting it would - but they are still resurrectable.

Comment: Not *just* like deleting it would.  Won't it still show up in searches?

Comment: @Kyralessa I just test-archived a card on my personal board, and it did not turn up in a search for its exact title.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess I was viewing the `archive` as a place to keep track of completed tasks and so it would be nice to keep it free of things that are simply mistakes... perhaps it won't make much difference in the long run though.

Comment: @DQd I keep a `Done` list all the way to the right on my board for things I've done. I archive things off of that list as they get older and less relevant.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense and it seems like that was the design intent as well...

Answer (score 5):

When clicking on a card, you will see the detail page, on the right bottom of the popup is a gray link : `delete this card`

Comment: I see only share, print and export :(

Comment: Are you admin on the board of the card?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was not logged in as the admin of the card. Done it.

Answer (score 1):

Click the card you want to Delete.
Click the `Archive` button on the Actions list on the left.

Once the card is Archived, `Delete` button automatically appears.

Comment: It can also be done without going through archiving. See [fiatjaf's answert](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/how-do-i-delete-a-list-or-card-in-trello/80600#80600).

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Archived Lists in a dump Board is the only solution, to date.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-click workaround is to click on the **`Make Template`** button and then **`Delete`** button.