# How can we delete a card in Trello?

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete a list or card in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/how-do-i-delete-a-list-or-card-in-trello)

I've added some test cards on this project, I wish not to have them anywhere.
I've archived them but that's absurd. Trying to find a trash can or delete text, no luck so far.

How can we delete cards ?